# How to resolve the Android Studio error where it cannot find the project's Manifest file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am migrating my legacy project from Eclipse to Android studio. I did the following things:

- Export and generate gradle build files in eclipse
- Imported the Gradle.build file in Android Studio
- Changed my gradle version dependencies to: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'

My root folder of the project contains 3 library projects: **Actionbarsherlock**, **Authbahn** and **library**. My root folder also contains the main project called **JohelpenHulpverlener**.

[image]

After resolving a lot of errors I get the following error:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':checkDebugManifest'.
> File 'C:\android\jeugdformaat\JohelpenHulpverlener\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.
```

My root build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(":actionbarsherlock")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle in the main project looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':autobahn')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand this, hopefully someone can help me out here!

Comment: You've added a bunch of stuff in your root-level gradle file, and I'm not sure if it belongs there -- you've also got a lot of stuff in what you say is your main project. Can you amend your question with more details about how your project is structured?

Comment: Will add an screenshot of my project structure!

Answer (score 5):

You've got a bunch of stuff in your root-level Gradle build file that's making the build system think there's an Android module there (it's not; it's a subdirectory below inside **JohelpenHulpverlener**) , and it's failing because it's not finding the manifest.

I think if you take a lot of stuff out of your root-level **build.gradle** file and replace it with the default version for new projects, which is this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

it will work.

Comment: Not the full answer but moving the android module configuration to the build.gradle files at the project level helped me get closer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have  tags on the outside like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    ...

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **build.gradle** file specify package name like

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 27
    versionName "1.5.6"
}
}
```

`applicationId "com.myapp"`  Here "com.myapp" is packagename of my app.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when migrating eclipse project to android studio.
The problem is that the root Gradle build file created by android studio is wrong and it should be like this :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Update : It seems the problem has been fixed by Android Studio's latest version 1.4, now we can easily import eclipse project into studio**

Answer (score 0):

Build->Rebuild solved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old post, but I helped a friend who is new to programming with this problem last night. Your suggestions were examined but did not apply. Their last action before the error was to add a list view layout to the project. I asked them to delete it and the errors vanished after a few moments.

I have not found any other post with this scenario and this conclusion so I thought sharing it here might help someone else.

Conclusion: Adding a new component to the wrong place may be another reason for such an error.